# hdwwz.exe behaves differently when called from a script

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

Windows 8 64 bit
Python 2.7.5

I'm trying to call the 'Add Hardware Wizard.' The program is located at c:\windows\system32\hdwwiz.exe. I'm able to call it, however the wizard gets stuck on the 'Choose Category' page if its called within a script. If I type 'hdwwiz' in the start menu search bar and run it, it works fine.

I've tried calling it several different ways. This is my latest.

```
import subprocess
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
subprocess.Popen(['hdwwiz.exe'],shell=True,startupinfo=si)
```

I don't understand why it acts differently.

Comment: Why do you want do call the wizard in a program? The wizard is for human interaction...

Comment: streamlining a process for the computer illiterate